# Imported csv data into mysql all ends up in one column

Tags: php, mysql

I want to import CSV file data to MySQL.
This is the code:

```
if (is_uploaded_file($_FILES['excelfile']['tmp_name'])) {
    echo "<h1>" . "File ". $_FILES['excelfile']['name'] ." Upload Done!" . "</h1>";
    echo "<h2>File Upload:</h2>";
    readfile($_FILES['excelfile']['tmp_name']);
}

$handle = fopen($_FILES['excelfile']['tmp_name'], "r");
while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
    $import="INSERT into city(city_name,days) values('$data[0]','$data[1]')";
    mysql_query($import) or die(mysql_error());
}

fclose($handle);
echo "<br><strong>Import Done.</strong><br>
```

The result just inserts into one column:
[image]

Comment: for example my csv data just column 1 = A, column 2 = 1 to 2,

Comment: That is not "showing", that is "quoting". We want (part of) the exact data [edit]ed into your question. Header, separators, delimiters, everything should be visible.

Comment: Stop using depricated `mysql_*` API. Use `mysqli_*`or `PDO`with prepared statements.

Comment: Post array data after read csv

Comment: Also there is a function called `Load data into` in mysql to load data from csv fle.

Comment: first thing i can tell you is that in your csv file, first col is No, you need to skip it so in query you have to insert 2nd and 3rd col like `values('$data[1]','$data[2]')";` and also you need to skip the first row of csv file

Comment: Why not use `LOAD DATA INFILE` to load the file directly into MySQL instead of doing lots of `INSERT`s?

Comment: It looks like your columns are separated by semicolon, not comma.

Comment: Can you paste a few lines of the CSV file into the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fields in your CSV file are separated by semicolon, but you're using comma in your call to `fgetcsv()`. Try

```
while ($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ";")) {
```

Comment: Waw that work.. Thank Barmar. I'm sorry i'm very newbie in php so i still use mysql..

Comment: You don't need to be an expert in PHP to tell the difference between comma and semicolon. You just need to be more careful.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the data on CSV file following code.

```
if ($_FILES['excelfile']['size'] > 0) {
    $mimes = array('application/vnd.ms-excel', 'text/plain', 'text/csv', 'text/tsv');
    //get the csv file
    $file = $_FILES['excelfile']['tmp_name'];
    $handle = fopen($file, "r");

    $data = array();
    while (!feof($handle)) {
        $data[] = fgetcsv($handle);
    }
}
```

Now you have data of CSV on `$data` array.So using `foreach` and then you can insert data into database.